# im getting this error :lexical error at line 9, column 16. Encountered :""(32).after:"NOT"

Tags: sparql, owl, rdfs, protege4

im trying to use one of the filters not exists. has checked this query with sparql validator its syntax is right. im using Twinkle sparql tool.

```
    # filename: ex067.rq
        PREFIX ab: <http://learningsparql.com/ns/addressbook#>  
          SELECT  ?first ?last
            WHERE
             { ?s ab:firstName ?first .
                 ?s ab:lastName ?last.
                           FILTER NOT EXISTS {?s ab:workTel ?workNum }
                                         }
```

Comment: Twinkle is very old -- 2007? - before SPARQL 1.1 (and before SPARQL 1.0 was even finished).

Comment: As @AndyS points out Twinkle won't support this syntax because it didn't exist at the time when Twinkle was written

Comment: ohhh okay thanks alot. i have windows 7 and i tried to run the same query from command line with this query 'arq --data -/sparql data/ex054.ttl --query -/sparql data/ex067.rq' when i run this it gives a message ONLY ONE QUERY STRING ALLOWED. i have set the envoronment variable correctly.

Comment: I am new to rdfdotnet and sparql. i want to learn about querying owl files with sparql and all the stuff. can u please kindly provide guidance on where to start?? @RobV thanks